# Cross-origin failure after changing to a different AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, dns, cross-domain

I have the following setup;
Front-end makes a request to an AWS load balancer, which in turn serves data from a AWS EC2 instance. The load balancer URL is behind a DNS. This always worked as expected.

After changing the DNS to point to a new load balancer from a new EC2 instance, I get a cross-origin error after performing a GET request to the load balancer. This leads me to believe I am missing something in either the new EC2 instance or load balancer setup. When I run the stack locally I get the same cross-origin error. However when I turn on the [allow cross origin chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) everything works as expected.

The cross-origin error:

> Failed to load https://ec2-dns.com/wms?request=GetCapabilities: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://frontend-dns.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Any ideas on what would cause this cross-origin error?

Comment: You probably want to update your question to include the exact error message you’re seeing in the devtools console. And to get more help, you can go to the Network pane in your devtools, and reload and then copy the details from the request(s) and response(s) there — including the HTTP status codes for the responses — and paste those into the question too

Comment: resources from ec2-dns.com should probably not be used, seems like your app needs to be explicitly configured with frontend-dns.com (otherwise it is using hostname of the instance to generate urls, resulting with this issue)

Comment: I solved it. It was a problem related to Tomcat. The CrosFilter was missing in the web.xml config of the new ec2 instance. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter Thanks for the help!